# How do you update message state for RoR applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to work out how to update states for messages. For example if an offer was made in a message, within a message thread with another user how do I update the status of that offer without affecting any previous offers?

I basically want the application to be able to take in offers and counter offers, but store each message with the newest being calculated from a set of inputs and the price of older messages being unaffected by the new message.

**Example:**

**1)** - John sends offer: £1000

**2)** *(**NOT LIKE THIS** - where the earlier message has been updated with the new price)*

- John sends offer: £3000
- James declines offer and offers a counter offer of £3000

**3)** *(**IDEALLY LIKE THIS** - regardless of number of messages and offers in the message thread)*

- John sends offer: £1000
- James declines offer and offers a counter offer of £3000

How do I store the values of price individually for each message between the two users?

Thanks :)

Comment: While, since you'll be storing the messages in the database, just have a price field on the messages model

Comment: Lists in (2) and (3) are identical. DRY up your question please :P

Comment: Done, I forgot to make that change before posting :S